# find inside json array in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I have in the MySql table column that called "more_data" and its contain json array:

```
[{
    "notes": null,
    "status": 0,
    "type_id": 1,
    "start_id": 1001
},
{
    "notes": null,
    "status": 1,
    "type_id": 2,
},
{
    "notes": null,
    "status": 1,
    "type_id": 3,
},
{
    "notes": null,
    "status": 1,
    "type_id": 4,
}]
```

I need to get only this JSON from the query but just where status is 1.
So I don't want to get the first element.
There is way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: "_and its contain json array_" As a string or is that a MySQL JSON field?

Comment: After you got the above JSON from MySQL. 
You have to parse it in php with foreach loop to get that specific records.

Comment: @kerbholz mysql json field (mysql 8)

Comment: please put controller code.

Answer (score 0):

If the "more_data" column is a type of JSON, You can get the values by whereJsonContains() function. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses

Otherwise, you have to decode the JSON and filter the array.

Comment: It is JSON field (mysql8) but the whereJsonContains dont work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a=YourModel::find($id);
$b=$a->more_data;
        $data=[];
        foreach($b as $c)
        {
            if(($c['status'])==1)
            {
                $data[]=$c;
            }
        }
dd($data);
```